# Concatenate files with awk

Tags: awk

First of all, I'm a noob with awk. That being said, I want to concatenate two files with awk, I mean:

File1:

```
267,783,607

270,248,003

272,690,813
```

File2:

```
1,636,096

1,533,887

1,426,044
```

Expected:

```
1,636,096 267,783,607
    
1,533,887 270,248,003
    
1,426,044 272,690,813
```

Additional context: these files come from doing:

```
# File1
curl -s https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2016/crime-in-the-u.s.-2016/topic-pages/tables/table-1 | pup --color "div#table-data-container td.group1 text{}"

# File2
curl -s https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2016/crime-in-the-u.s.-2016/topic-pages/tables/table-1 | pup --color "div#table-data-container td.group2 text{}"
```

I was trying to do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a=$1; next} {print $1, a}' <(curl -s https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2016/crime-in-the-u.s.-2016/topic-pages/tables/table-1 | pup --color "div#table-data-container td.group2 text{}") <(curl -s https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2016/crime-in-the-u.s.-2016/topic-pages/tables/table-1 | pup --color "div#table-data-container td.group1 text{}")
```

But I don't know why I get this output, since the last awk command it's supposed to print only the first record of the first file stored in `a` and the first record of the second file (there's something I' missing):

```
1,248,185
267,783,607 1,248,185
 1,248,185
270,248,003 1,248,185
 1,248,185
272,690,813 1,248,185
 1,248,185
281,421,906 1,248,185
 1,248,185
285,317,559 1,248,185
 1,248,185
287,973,924 1,248,185
 1,248,185
290,788,976 1,248,185
 1,248,185
293,656,842 1,248,185
 1,248,185
296,507,061 1,248,185
 1,248,185
299,398,484 1,248,185
 1,248,185
301,621,157 1,248,185
 1,248,185
304,059,724 1,248,185
 1,248,185
307,006,550 1,248,185
 1,248,185
309,330,219 1,248,185
 1,248,185
311,587,816 1,248,185
 1,248,185
313,873,685 1,248,185
 1,248,185
316,497,531 1,248,185
 1,248,185
318,907,401 1,248,185
 1,248,185
320,896,618 1,248,185
 1,248,185
323,127,513 1,248,185
```

I know I can do:

```
paste <(curl -s https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2016/crime-in-the-u.s.-2016/topic-pages/tables/table-1 | pup --color "div#table-data-container td.group2 text{}") <(curl -s https://ucr.fbi.gov/crime-in-the-u.s/2016/crime-in-the-u.s.-2016/topic-pages/tables/table-1 | pup --color "div#table-data-container td.group1 text{}")
```

And get what I want:

```
1,636,096   267,783,607
    
1,533,887   270,248,003
    
1,426,044   272,690,813
    
1,425,486   281,421,906
    
1,439,480   285,317,559
    
1,423,677   287,973,924
    
1,383,676   290,788,976
    
1,360,088   293,656,842
    
1,390,745   296,507,061
    
1,435,123   299,398,484
    
1,422,970   301,621,157
    
1,394,461   304,059,724
    
1,325,896   307,006,550
    
1,251,248   309,330,219
    
1,206,005   311,587,816
    
1,217,057   313,873,685
    
1,168,298   316,497,531
    
1,153,022   318,907,401
    
1,199,310   320,896,618
    
1,248,185   323,127,513
```

But the idea is to do it with awk just for learning.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You cold simply do `awk 'FNR==NR{arr[FNR]=$0;next} {print $0,arr[FNR]}'  file2  file1` in `awk`.

Comment: as for *why* your current `awk` code is generating the wrong result ... `FNR==NR{a=$1; next}` says that for each line from the 1st file you are to store field #1 in the single variable `a`, with the net result being that once you've completed processing the 1st file you have one variable (`a`) that contains the first field of the last line from the 1st file

Comment: `paste file2 file1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{f1[FNR]=$0; next} 
{print $0, f1[FNR]}' file1 file2
```

Or use [paste](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html):

```
paste file2 file1
```

Either prints:

```
1,636,096 267,783,607

1,533,887 270,248,003

1,426,044 272,690,813
```

Comment: The logic in your comment is: 

1. If the number of records for `file1` (`FNR`, I guess it resets for each file) is the same as the total number of records (`NR`, it doesnt reset), then store the field $0 (the whole line) in `f1` at index `FNR` and do not apply more rules to this record (`next`).
2. Then, print the whole line of `file2` taking advantage of the reset of `FNR`, so you can index the whole `f1` array in the correct order. 

Am I right?

Comment: Yes -- you are correct. The `FNR==NR` is idiomatic awk for 'the first file' since that is the only time that is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read a line from the second file from within the AWK script itself:

```
awk '{getline x <"2.txt"; print x, $0}' 1.txt
```

This might not be as neat but scales to more than two files since the `NR==FNR` trick only works when there's two files.

Comment: Beware of unprotected `getline`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score -1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file1.txt` content be

```
267,783,607

270,248,003

272,690,813
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
1,636,096

1,533,887

1,426,044
```

then

```
awk '{arr[FNR]=(FNR==NR?$0:arr[FNR] " " $0)}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i+=1){print arr[i]}}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

gives output

```
1,636,096 267,783,607
 
1,533,887 270,248,003
 
1,426,044 272,690,813
```

Assumption: all files have equal number of lines. Explanation: I use so-called ternary operator (condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse) so first file (`FNR==NR`) I do set value in array `arr` under key being number of line in file to line and for all other I append space character and whole line to value in array in `arr`. After all files are done I use `for` loop to output values from array `arr` in desired order. This code might be used with more than 2 files as long as all have exact same number of lines.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*